# Android - Glide ".placeholder" method not recognized

Tags: kotlin, android-glide

I have a recycler view. In the adapter's `onBindViewHolder` method I have the following code to load an image:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Log.i("TEST-APP", "Binding View Holder")

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(items[position])
                .placeholder(R.drawable.animated_loading_icon)
                .into(holder.imageView)
    }
```

However, Android Studio is saying that "placeholder" is an unresolved reference. This is confusing because the [documentation](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-placeholders-fade-animations) indicates that this is the correct way to load a placeholder.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, here are my imports in the `RecyclerViewAdapter` class

```
package com.example.myname.recylerviewtest

import android.content.Context
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.util.Log
import android.view.*
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.recyclerview_item_column.view.*
```

Lastly, here are my dependencies in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
api 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As shown in the Glide [documentation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html):

> Most options in Glide can be applied using the RequestOptions class
>   and the apply() method.
>
> Use request options to apply (among others):
>
> ```
> Placeholders
> Transformations
> Caching Strategies
> Component specific options, like encode quality, or decode Bitmap configurations.
> ```

So, if you want to use placeholder, you have two options.

One of them is to do it this way:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(items[position])
    .apply(RequestOptions()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.animated_loading_icon)
    )
    .into(holder.imageView)
```

And the other option would be to implement the [Generated API](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html#generated-api)